# Custom Attribute generation for Specflow

Tags: .net, testing, mstest, specflow

I have created a custom attribute for unit tests and integ tests that are being run on MSTest. I see that that specflows are being created so they are understood by MSTest. Is it possible for me to inject my custom attribute [CustomTestClass] instead of the standard [TestClass] Has anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `tags` functionality of specflow, it will create custom attributes for you. So for example:

```
@CustomAttribute
Feature: ThisIsMyFeature
```

Will create the `[CustomAttribute]` for this feature. Same can be done on Scenario level.

Comment: great thank you for your quick response. I will give this a go and play around with it and mark it this as the answer if it works

Comment: unfortunately that is not what I was looking for - that will just create a category with my customattribute but my attribute needs to replace the [TestClass] of unit tests.. I think I've found a solution here http://specflow.org/documentation/Plugins/ by creating a custom plugin. Thanks for your help anyway